# Как использовать pool.map?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прочитал, что могу ускорить работу функции map, использовав multiprocessing, а именно pool.map, но при запуске программы возникает ошибка, никак не могу поять что не так

```js
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # save dict to json
    with open('date.json') as jd:
        newdict = json.loads(jd.read())
        jd.close()

    random.seed(64)

    instName = 'C204'

    unitCost = 1
    initCost = 0
    waitCost = 0
    delayCost = 0

    indSize = 15
    popSize = 400
    cxPb = 0.85
    mutPb = 0.02
    NGen = 300

    exportCSV = False

    toolbox = base.Toolbox()
    creator.create('FitnessMax', base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
    creator.create('Individual', list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

    pool = Pool() #!!!!!!
    toolbox.register("map", pool.map)
    
    toolbox.register('indexes', random.sample, range(1, indSize + 1), indSize)
    toolbox.register('individual', tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.indexes)

    toolbox.register('population', tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
    toolbox.register('evaluate', evalVRPTW, instance=newdict, unitCost=unitCost, initCost=initCost, waitCost=waitCost,
                     delayCost=delayCost)
    toolbox.register('select', tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)
    toolbox.register("mate", cxPartialyMatched)
    toolbox.register("mutate", mutShuffleIndexes, indpb=0.05)

    pop = toolbox.population(n=popSize)

    # Evaluate the entire population
    fitnesses = list(map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))

    for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit

    # Begin the evolution
    for g in range(NGen):

        # Select the next generation individuals
        offspring = toolbox.select(pop, len(pop))

        # Vary the pool of individuals
        offspring = varAnd(offspring, toolbox, cxPb, mutPb)

        # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
        invalidInd = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        fitnesses = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalidInd) #!!!!!!!
        for ind, fit in zip(invalidInd, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

        ## The population is entirely replaced by the offspring
        pop[:] = offspring

    bestInd = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
```

olbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalidInd)
        for ind, fit in zip(invalidInd, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

```
    pop[:] = offspring

bestInd = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
```

В результате получаю:

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Individual' on module 'deap.creator' from 'C:\Users\Fomichev_AN.VAIO1\Envs\VRPTW\deap\creator.py'

Comment: Александр, вас не смутило, что сайт с префиксом **ru.** и тут русскоязычные вопросы? Переведите, пожалуйста, вопрос на русский, чтобы его не закрыли.

Comment: Приведённого кода не достаточно для воспроизведения ошибки, поэтому можно только предположить что toolbox.evaluate не достаточно чистая функция и использует какие либо вычисления (кроме значений из invalidInd) сделанные до создания `Pool`. В момент создания `Pool` фактически происходит fork просесса. Всё что было вычеслено/создано/объявлено после создания Pool должно либо передаться в параметрах, либо оно не должно использоваться.